# Web Scraping img files

Tags: html, web-applications, web-scraping

I'm scraping through a website to get product informations to be used on my web app.

An example of a product attributes are

```
<p class="img"><img src="http://gs25appimg.gsretail.com/imgsvr/item/GD_8801069187457_001.jpg" alt="유어스)남양망고라떼PET300ML"></p>
<p class="tit">유어스)남양망고라떼PET300ML</p>
<p class="price"><span class="cost">2,000<span>원</span></span></p>
<div class="flag_box ONE_TO_ONE"><p class="flg01"><span>1+1</span></p></div>
```

My plan is to store all of the products' information on my server and call them from my web app.

Is it smart move to store img files to my server/link them on mysql DB then call it from the web or will it be fast enough to just call the img on my web app using the original img src url(from the original website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the performance of your setup compared to theirs for any given user depending on where they are on the planet. I think it's safe to assume that any differences would be marginal assuming you are serving up the same-sized image. However, the original website might not like it if you are hot linking to their images. Also if they change their filenames or images your links will break.